# Add a user to multiple Azure databases

Tags: database, azure, user-controls

I am looking to add a user to multiple Azure databases. We have multiple subscriptions and each subscription has multiple Azure databases. We have a requirement to add the same SQL user to all the databases (dev environment). Is there an easy way to do it using PS?

Answer (score 0):

On-premises security at the server / database level SQL Server and Azure SQL Database are fairly similar, however there are some significant differences.

The first distinction is the idea of a contained user, which is a user who is not associated with a login and whose authentication takes place in Azure Active Directory or in the database itself. Traditional SQL Server logins with a user in a database mapped to it continue to exist, but this departs from the notion of the necessary login that grants access to the server and the user that grants access to the database. Users who are self-contained make the database more portable.

Conventional database level roles such as db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin, and so on are the same, however traditional server level roles such as sysadmin, serveradmin, and so on do not exist in Azure SQL Database. There are, however, two server admin roles: db_manager (similar to db_creator), which can build and drop databases, and loginmanager (similar to securityadmin), which can create new logins.

-- create SQL auth login from master
CREATE LOGIN test
WITH PASSWORD = 'SuperSecret!'

Connect to your Azure SQL Database server as an administrator and choose the database to which you wish to add the user(s). Create a SQL authentication contained user called 'test' with the password 'SuperSecret!' and assign it the db_datareader and db_datawriter responsibilities.

```
-- select your db in the dropdown and create a user mapped to a login 
CREATE USER [test] 
FOR LOGIN [test] 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo; 
  
-- add user to role(s) in db 
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [test]; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [test];
```

Alternative here is a PowerShell command to run:

```
$instance = 'localhost'
$dbs = dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\$instance\DEFAULT\Databases
$sql = 'CREATE USER [foo] FROM LOGIN [foo]; ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [foo];'
$dbs | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Database $_.Name -Query $sql}
```